# Javascript wait for async calls to finish before return

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have to make a lot of asynchronous calls to an application, to get some fields (from Microsoft Project).

This is how an async call looks like

```
Office.context.document.getTaskFieldAsync(GUID, Office.ProjectTaskFields.Start,
    function (result) {
        if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
            taskdata.taskStart = result.value.fieldValue;
            }
            else {
                app.showNotification('Error 33:', result.error.message);
           }
     }
);
```

I want to have a subfunction that looks like the following :

```
function GetAllFields(GUID) {
    var taskdata;
    Office.context.document.getTaskFieldAsync(GUID,Name....
       ....
       taskdata.Name= result.value.fieldValue;
       ....
    );
    Office.context.document.getTaskFieldAsync(GUID,Start....
       ....
       taskdata.Start = result.value.fieldValue;
       ....
    );
    Office.context.document.getTaskFieldAsync(GUID,Finish....
       ....
       taskdata.Finish= result.value.fieldValue;
       ....
    );

    return taskdata
}
```

The problem is, that the taskdata object is returned **null** before any of the async calls firing, and that's normal behaviour, but I need a great way of chaining these events, or  returning only if all the async calls were done.

**UPDATE**

After nesting the async calls into one another, and returning the **taskdata** object only in the deepest call, i thought it would fix the issue, but in the parent function, where I call GetAllFields(GUID), it goes forward, and it's not waiting for it to return...

Comment: Make a  new call when the preceding call's readyState changes and in the final asynchronous call return the tastdata object. May be !!!

Comment: Ok, I nested the async calls into one another, but stil... it's not working properly. In the main function, where I call this GetAllFields() function, it goes forward, and it's not waiting for it, to finish.